# Sending the same command to many opened Konsole sessions and tabs

Tags: linux, konsole

I have a linux machine with KDES. 
I have many Konsole sessions opened. Each one has few opened tabs.
Occasionally, I'm changing some basic configuration such as adding alias or altering a bit the prompt. In that case, I would like to update all the opened shells about it. Such as sending "source ~/.aliases" to all of the shells.

I have found tmux, but it create its own arrangement of windows. I however, want to use the already existing arrangement of konsole windows.

I also found qdbus, but those commands seem to works only on the current konsole and not other konsole processes.

Any help will be appreciated.